# normalizer info for subgroups

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

In [1], Griess classified the maximal nontoral elementary abelian subgroups of algebraic groups. For the exceptional types, normalizer info was also given. Is there any work out there providing normalizer info of nontoral elementary abelian subgroups of the algebraic group of type C?

**Reference**

[1] Robert Griess, JR., *Elementary abelian p-subgroups of algebraic groups*, Geom. Dedicata 39 (1991), no. 3, 253-305.